# タッチを認識するエリアを広げる処理を関数化したい

Tags: android, java

以下のコードは、Android Developersサイトに掲載されているもので、ビューのタッチを認識する範囲を大きくする処理です。
自身のプロジェクトに貼り付け、想定の動きをすることを確認できたのですが、この処理を関数化したいと考えています。
parentView、myButtonの部分を引数にして渡す関数にしてみたのですが、「variable is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final」とエラー表示が出るのですが、どうのように修正すればよいかが分かりません。

どのように記述すれば、素敵な関数にできるでしょうか？

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Get the parent view
        View parentView = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

        parentView.post(new Runnable() {
            // Post in the parent's message queue to make sure the parent
            // lays out its children before you call getHitRect()
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // The bounds for the delegate view (an ImageButton
                // in this example)
                Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
                ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
                myButton.setEnabled(true);
                myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Touch occurred within ImageButton touch region.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // The hit rectangle for the ImageButton
                myButton.getHitRect(delegateArea);

                // Extend the touch area of the ImageButton beyond its bounds
                // on the right and bottom.
                delegateArea.right += 100;
                delegateArea.bottom += 100;

                // Instantiate a TouchDelegate.
                // "delegateArea" is the bounds in local coordinates of
                // the containing view to be mapped to the delegate view.
                // "myButton" is the child view that should receive motion
                // events.
                TouchDelegate touchDelegate = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea,
                        myButton);

                // Sets the TouchDelegate on the parent view, such that touches
                // within the touch delegate bounds are routed to the child.
                if (View.class.isInstance(myButton.getParent())) {
                    ((View) myButton.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問の中でエラー文だけ書かれても、どういうコードを書いてエラーが出たのかが分からないのでなんとも答えにくいのですが、多分こういうコードを書いたんじゃないかなと推測します。

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Get the parent view
        View parentView = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
        // メソッド呼び出し
        touchDelegate(parentView, myButton);
    }

    public void touchDelegate(View parentView, ImageButton myButton){
        parentView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
                // この辺でエラー
                myButton.setEnabled(true);
                myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Touch occurred within ImageButton touch region.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                myButton.getHitRect(delegateArea);

                delegateArea.right += 100;
                delegateArea.bottom += 100;

                TouchDelegate touchDelegate = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea,
                        myButton);

                if (View.class.isInstance(myButton.getParent())) {
                    ((View) myButton.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

このときに質問内容のエラー「variable is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final」と出たのだとしたら、メソッド内で使用しているmyButtonのところじゃないかなと思います。

```
parentView.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        myButton.~~; // <- ここ
    }
});
```

これは、メソッドの引数であるmyButtonがfinal修飾子が付いていないのにインナークラス内で使用されようとしているときに起こるコンパイルエラー、つまり文法ミスです。(Javaの文法を勉強しましょう)
このエラーの回避方法は単純で、引数にfinalを付けるだけです。

```
    // ImageButtonの前にfinalを付ける
    public void touchDelegate(View parentView, final ImageButton myButton){
        parentView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
```

どうしてfinalがついてないといけないのか……などは、ググれば一発で出てくると思うので、色々と調べてみるといいんじゃないんでしょうか。(「Java インナークラス final」とか)
ちなみに、このエラー文をそのままGoogleの検索ボックスに入れて検索すると、たくさん答えが出てくるので、それも参考にしてみればいいんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: エラー箇所、内容ともご指摘の通りです。
finalは入れてみていたのですが、エディタのエラー色の波線が消えず、問題が解消していないものと勘違いしておりました。波線が残っても「！」は消えたので実行してみました所、想定通りに動かすことができました！
お手間をおかけし大変失礼いたしました。